Detect Bad or Weak Sectors and Files Affected
I am trying to diagnose a HDD and have done some research in regards to detect bad sectors and find the files which resides on them. Some have suggested nfi.exe where we enter the Logical Sector number of the bad sector and it outputs the file names. Another suggested using HD Sentinel to check the disk for the bad block first, then we can view which files are on it so that we know which to restore from a backup.
However, I still haven't confirmed how the process work if the drive has full drive encryption like if it is locked with Bitlocker or Veracrypt. I assume we first unlock it first before running checking software like HD Sentinel?
I did a random test once where I ran nfi on an unlocked Bitlocker drive by providing a logical sector. It gave me a file that resides there as expected. The next day I unlocked the drive, I did the same test and it says no file is residing there?? I did not write anything to the drive in between nor ran any other tests so I'm thinking I might be using nfi.exe wrong. However because of this, I would like to clarify how to properly identify files affected by bad sectors on bitlockered drive. Do encryption move data around sectors resulting in different files on that sector at different time?
If not, I believe the procedure is straightforward where we unlock drive first and then maybe run HD Sentinel to do the checks. But I feel like confirming this first in case encryption does change the equation. Don't want to end up thinking I knew which file was affected when that one was not the one.

Encryption sits 'over' the level bad sectors are in.  I suspect an unlocked bitlocker drive isn't decrypted on disk, just decrypted as its used, which might be why files 'move'

In this case, if there was a bad sector how do we locate the affected file if that sector can end up with different files on different days?

In theory, modern drives abstract that out - it'll quietly reallocate the sector on the next write I suspect.  Modern filesystems also tend to have some level of error correction. Use filesystem tools to find damaged files, use SMART and other low level tools to diagnose drive issues.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Thanks for the reply. Do you have a suggestion which file system tools would be good for this?
